# Lower non-dimmable ceiling light brightness

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, led

I've bought https://hausofinteriors.com/collections/ceiling-lighting/products/the-cloud and had it installed in a home in the UK. It's *incredibly* bright, to the point where it's unusable. I'd like to lower the brightness.

The website, and the company when I emailed them, say that it's not dimmable and it can't be made less bright.

Is that true? It has a voltage range of 90 - 260V. If I restricted that to a lower value, would that work? Or is there another solution?

Here's a photo of the internals of the ceiling light, before it was installed by an electrician:

[image]

Comment: That range of voltages is to allow the same fixture to be sold in multiple countries without having to change any of the electrical components. For example in the US we use a nominal 120V system, but it can vary from about 100-140v. In the UK, you use 240V, but you'll actually get around 220-260V. This light can survive all that, but will still produce the same number of _lumens_, no mater what the input voltage.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. ‍♂️ Thank you! That idea of mine won't work then!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll have much luck trying to lower the line side since it's a regulated, constant secondary and will probably just shut down if the line side goes below 90VAC. Since the specs state that the bulbs are wedge type, you might be able to replace them with lower wattage bulbs or at least get some sunshade gel material like they use for theater lights to dim or change color.

Comment: 90V?  not what it says on the label.

Comment: @Jasen  It's what it says in the specs and what the OP says.

Comment: I'm guessing that they really have two different models, and ship whichever suits the customer (possibly based on shipping address)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to spend some time figuring out how I'd be able to replace the wedge bulbs and then look for lower wattage ones. I didn't know about sunshade gel (and similar products) so I'm also going to see what's available for those where I am.

Another answer mentioned the discrepancy in the supply voltage from the website to the product, so I'm going to clarify that with the company.

Comment: If you can't replace the lamps & want to go with a 'sunshade gel' then your search term is "neutral density filter sheet" - that will point you in the right direction. It's something used in the movie/photography industry - check specs before purchase, but it should be good to very high temperatures, as they put it in front of lighting that reaches several hundred degrees centigrade [it's used on 18,000 W lamps, so no domestic lamp is going to hurt it at all]. It changes only the 'brightness' but not the colour. A value of 1.0 is 'half brightness'.

Comment: @Tetsujin, perfect, thank you. My other search term(s) weren't showing me particularly what I think I would need! That's a good note about the temperatures.  E.g. something like [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/164125660542) would allow me to see the effects and find a preference? (Of course, just on a small patch of the overall lighting from the ceiling fixture!)

Comment: That's the stuff, yes. Wish you luck & hope you can get it to flex nicely into what's a bit of an awkward space. [Obviously when they use it on cine lights they don't care if it creases a bit, they just clamp it to the frame with enormous bulldog clips & don't care what it looks like.]

Answer (score 1):

replace the LED driver module with a lower current one, or with an adjustable one.

you appear to have a two channel 230mA LED driver.

[image]

output is 60 to 145V at 230mA (twice)

so look for a replacement that meets those specifications at lower current

If you can measure the LED voltage you won't need to find a driver that covers the whole 60 to 145 volt range.

I note that for the supply voltage the web site says "90-260V" but the product says "180-265V".
Seeing as they made untrue claims about the input voltage range you could possibly use consumer protection laws to force them to give you a refund.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, I see—here's the wedge LED bulbs AND then this LED driver.

Q. How does the "(twice)" part come into play?

Q. Dumb question, but, for measuring the LED voltage, you mean the wedge LED bulbs? Or what's actually coming out of the current driver to power those bulbs?

That's a really good point about the supply voltage discrepancy. I'm going to look into that and see if I can do what you've suggested.

Comment: you need to measure the wires coming out of the led driver, red to white, red to yellow, while it's all working